# queue multithreaded implementation not running threads for the entire list it iterates over

Tags: python, multithreading, yfinance

I am following a multithreading guide at https://www.shanelynn.ie/using-python-threading-for-multiple-results-queue/. I am trying to implement a Queue version as the threaded version works but will not scale if the spreadsheet grows to over 400 items.

The example sheet can be found at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f-oAv18OwlXVXt9odCxzSVF7axt06jc8Tzz1cqDozmM

The code for the queue is as follows:

```
from __future__ import print_function

from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread

import google.auth
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

import yfinance, time

start = time.time()

STOCKS_INTEREST_LIST = "1f-oAv18OwlXVXt9odCxzSVF7axt06jc8Tzz1cqDozmM"
    
def get_new_row_data(old_row):
    try:
        print(old_row[0])
        ticker = old_row[0]
        if ticker:
            try:
                yahoo_stock_obj = yfinance.Ticker(ticker.upper())
                info = yahoo_stock_obj.get_info()
                print(ticker)
                current_price = info.get('currentPrice', '')
                if not current_price:
                    try:
                        current_price = old_row[1]
                    except:
                        pass
                else:
                    if current_price > 10:
                        current_price = round(current_price, 1)
                print(current_price)
                dividend_yield_from_yahoo = info.get('dividendYield', '')
                if dividend_yield_from_yahoo:
                    dividend_yield = round(dividend_yield_from_yahoo * 100, 1)
                elif dividend_yield_from_yahoo == None or dividend_yield_from_yahoo == '':
                    print("couldnt get a dividend yield for {ticker}".format(ticker=ticker))
                    try:
                        dividend_yield = old_row[2]
                    except:
                        dividend_yield = ''
                else:
                    print("dividend_yield_from_yahoo:")
                    print(dividend_yield_from_yahoo)
                    raise Exception("unknown type of dividend_yield_from_yahoo")

                data_row = [ticker, current_price, dividend_yield]
                return data_row
            except:
                return old_row
    except IndexError:
        print("index error")
        return ['', '', '']
    except:
        print("unknown error iterating over rows")


def get_values(spreadsheet_id, range_name):
    """
    Creates the batch_update the user has access to.
    Load pre-authorized user credentials from the environment.
    TODO(developer) - See https://developers.google.com/identity
    for guides on implementing OAuth2 for the application.
        """
    creds, _ = google.auth.default()
    # pylint: disable=maybe-no-member
    try:
        service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

        result = service.spreadsheets().values().get(
            spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range=range_name).execute()
        rows = result.get('values', [])
        # print(rows)
        # print(f"{len(rows)} rows retrieved")
        return rows
    except HttpError as error:
        print(f"An error occurred: {error}")
        return error


def update_values(spreadsheet_id, range_name, value_input_option,
                  values):
    """
    Creates the batch_update the user has access to.
    Load pre-authorized user credentials from the environment.
    TODO(developer) - See https://developers.google.com/identity
    for guides on implementing OAuth2 for the application.
        """
    creds, _ = google.auth.default()
    # pylint: disable=maybe-no-member
    try:

        service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

        body = {
            'values': values
        }
        result = service.spreadsheets().values().update(
            spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range=range_name,
            valueInputOption=value_input_option, body=body).execute()
        print(f"{result.get('updatedCells')} cells updated.")
        return result
    except HttpError as error:
        print(f"An error occurred: {error}")
        return error


def run_queue(rows_index):
    stock_tickers_rows = get_values(STOCKS_INTEREST_LIST, rows_index)

    numthreads = min(50, len(stock_tickers_rows))
    q = Queue(maxsize=numthreads)

    results = [{} for row in stock_tickers_rows]

    for i in range(len(stock_tickers_rows)):
        q.put((i, stock_tickers_rows[i]))

    def get_new_result(queue, results_array):
        while not queue.empty():
            work = queue.get()
            data = get_new_row_data(work[1])
            results_array[work[0]] = data
            queue.task_done()
        return True

    # new_results = get_new_results(q, results)

    for i in range(len(stock_tickers_rows)):
        print('Starting thread ', i)
        worker = Thread(target=get_new_result, args=(q, results))
        worker.setDaemon(True)    #setting threads as "daemon" allows main program to
                                  #exit eventually even if these dont finish correctly.
        worker.start()

    #now we wait until the queue has been processed
    q.join()

    print("length of results: {length}".format(length=len(results)))
    print('It took ', time.time() - start, ' seconds.')
    return results



if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Pass: spreadsheet_id, and range_name
    ROWS_INDEX = "A2:C40"
    results = run_queue(ROWS_INDEX)
    print(results)
    # stock_tickers_rows = get_values(STOCKS_INTEREST_LIST, ROWS_INDEX)
    # new_data = gather_new_data(stock_tickers_rows)
    # print("\nupdating spreadsheet now")
    # time.sleep(5)
    # update_values(STOCKS_INTEREST_LIST,
    #               ROWS_INDEX, "USER_ENTERED", results)
```

This previous threaded version I did is very fast, since going one request at a time takes 7 seconds per request times 145:

```
It took  103.4163749217987  seconds.
```

But this Queue version puts 38 items in the queue and then returns 39 results, even though I requested it to iterate over the len of the stock_tickers_rows:

```
Starting thread  38

length of results: 39
It took  39.11507272720337  seconds.
[['abbv', 139.0, 4.0], ['d', 83.8, 3.1], ['ed', 98.7, 3.2], ['enb', 43.5, 6.2], ['gis', 77.6, 2.8], ['mmm', 141.8, 4.1], ['sbra', 15.6, 7.6], ['bldg', '', '7.2'], ['kbwy', '', '5.7'], ['good', 19.9, 7.5], ['roof', '23.9', '4.1'], ['netl', '26.7', '3.8'], ['nnn', 45.8, 4.7], ['riet', '13.6', '7'], ['lxp', 10.6, 4.5], ['wfc', 44.5, 2.7], ['c', 51.1, 4.0], ['whr', 165.4, 4.2], ['bx', 102.1, 5.1], ['ms', 88.3, 3.5], ['pnw', 76.2, 4.4], ['hmc', 26.7, 5.2], ['wash', 54.0, 4.0], ['spy', '411', '1.4'], ['spyd', '40', '4'], ['mga', 59.3, 3.1], ['ry', 97.3, 4.1], ['td', 66.4, 4.2], ['dvn', 70.5, 9.1], ['wen', 20.1, 2.5], ['glpi', 51.0, 5.4], ['cube', 48.2, 3.4], ['reg', 62.6, 3.9], ['lcii', 127.0, 3.3], ['dbmf', '32', '4.6'], ['jpw', '111', '3.6'], ['eix', 69.4, 3.9], ['uht', 52.8, 5.3], ['xshd', '20', '5.1']]
```

There are 145 stock tickers that should be updated. How can I get this queue threading to run all 145 tickers while maxing out at 50 threads at a time?

setting the index to A2:C145 causes the script to hang and do nothing for several minutes. When I cancel it with ctrl+c this is the message:

```
in)$ python3 read_values_multithreaded_que.py 
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cchilders/projects/update_stocks_interest_list/read_values_multithreaded_que.py", line 152, in <module>
    results = run_queue(ROWS_INDEX)
  File "/home/cchilders/projects/update_stocks_interest_list/read_values_multithreaded_que.py", line 121, in run_queue
    q.put((i, stock_tickers_rows[i]))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/queue.py", line 140, in put
    self.not_full.wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 320, in wait
    waiter.acquire()
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: The range `A2:C40` spans 39 rows.  Why are you expecting 145?

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: yes thank you i thought it was still up to 200. running it now it hangs and does nothing, no  print statements at all

Comment: setting it from A2:C40 runs quickly, setting it to A2:C145 to run all causes the script to hang from run and do nothing with no prints

Comment: its been hanging in the prompt for 3 minutes now with no output or error messages